# Optimize repeatable anonymous delegates C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I register policies for authorization. Claim `options` it's array of abilities users on site `['cm', 'wtm', 'um']`. With the help of RequireAssertion check availability required ability. How I can optimize this repeatable code? Thank you!

```
    policyBuilder.AddPolicy("UmPolicy", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
        {
            var optionsSerializedArray = context.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimType.Options);

            if (optionsSerializedArray == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            var deserializedOptionsUser = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[]>(optionsSerializedArray);
            var option = deserializedOptionsUser?.SingleOrDefault(value => value == "um");

            return option != null;
        });
    });

    policyBuilder.AddPolicy("CmPolicy", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
        {
            var optionsSerializedArray = context.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimType.Options);

            if (optionsSerializedArray == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            var deserializedOptionsUser = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[]>(optionsSerializedArray);
            var option = deserializedOptionsUser?.SingleOrDefault(value => value == "cm");

            return option != null;
        });

        policyBuilder.AddPolicy("WtmPolicy", policy =>
        {
            policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
            {
                var optionsSerializedArray = context.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimType.Options);

                if (optionsSerializedArray == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                var deserializedOptionsUser = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[]>(optionsSerializedArray);
                var option = deserializedOptionsUser?.SingleOrDefault(value => value == "wtm");

                return option != null;
            });
        });
```

Comment: Can you please help us with type definitions? There is no way we can try this code on our end since individual type names are not known. Guess work wont help finding right answer. If possible can you please add encompassing method name and signature? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Dictionary to store all policy names and write the code in a loop over dictionary items.

```
Dictionary<string, string> policies = new() { { "UmPolicy", "um" }, { "CmPolicy", "cm" }, { "WtmPolicy", "wtm" } };

foreach(var item in policies)
{
    policyBuilder.AddPolicy(item.Key, policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
        {
            var optionsSerializedArray = context.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimType.Options);

            if (optionsSerializedArray == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            var deserializedOptionsUser = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[]>(optionsSerializedArray);
            var option = deserializedOptionsUser?.SingleOrDefault(value => value == item.Value);

            return option != null;
        });
    });
}
```